# Archiving the dhcpd.lease file

Tags: linux, dhcp

I need to archive the dhcpd.lease file data for legal purposes.  I need to retain all the dhcp lease information with the UID from the 1st day.

According to dhcpd.lease man page this file is over written from time to time, however it does not mention the frequency or on what condition is over written. I would like to find out what will be the best way to archive the dhcpd.lease file?
I do have the dhcpd.lease file and the dhcps.lease~ backup on the system available, but no sure on how often this file is updated -- should I be archiving it weekly, monthly or some other way?

Comment: Strange requirement. I've never seen this type of logging mandated.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're obligated to specifically keep copies of `dhcp.leases`, which is highly unlikely, you will be much better off keeping a copy of your dhcp daemon's log.

The `dhcp.leases` files is written to (and changed) every time a new lease is granted. The log is instead appended, may contain more information (such as DHCPNAK messages) and can be rotated so that is it no longer being written too. There are more virtues of logs, but I think that should be sufficient for now.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to log the uid, which is not shown in the daemon log, by default at least. The dhcp clients are on an LNS, and I only see LNS's mac address as uid for each leased IP, but I need to see the uid, which is the username of the client, and is contained in the dhcpd.leases file.

Comment: To be clear, by uid you mean the dhcp-client identifier and not the user account used to log into a L2TP Network Server, yes?

Comment: sorry, I should have been clear. Yes by "uid" I meant the user account used to log into an L2TP network.

Comment: excerpt from dhcpd.lease file;                                             <lease xx.xx.xx.xx {
  starts 2 2012/08/14 11:07:11;
  ends 2 2012/08/14 12:07:11;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
  uid "\user@dsl";
"

Answer (score 2):

You'll be much better off by reconfiguring your DHCP server to log the user account information.

Take a look at the `log` configuration option offered by isc-dhcpd. For example, here is a fairly simple example of how to log when a particular device is detected on the network:

```
class "SPA942" {
   log(info, "Linksys SPA942 detected");
   match if option vendor-class-identifier = "LINKSYS SPA-942";
   option tftp-server-name "phoneserver.example.com";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to archive the `dhcpd.leases` file you need to use something like [`famd`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/famd.8.php) to monitor it and copy it when it changes/gets replaced.
There is some good documentation on using `famd` around on the internet - [This old Linux Dev Center article is probably a good starting point](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2004/12/16/fam.html).

Archiving this way is likely to be space (or at least file/inode) intensive - Based on your comments to 84104's answer you are probably better off logging the user ID from whatever service is performing authentication for your L2TP tunnels. (If you're not performing authentication then the whole thing is pointless: I could send whatever the heck I want as my UID and you'd just log it, so my UID is `HaHa@HackedYou` :-)